# Keeping a large table into one page in ssrs 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a quite big table in the ssrs 2008. When I run the report, everything is good on the web. But when I save the report as pdf, the table is displayed into 2 pages instead one single page.

I tried to set InteractiveSize -> height:0 cm and I selected "keep together in one page if possible" in my tablix properties. Both did not solve my issue. Any more ideas? I would appreciate if someone helps.

Thanks

Comment: The `InteractiveHeight` property is only applicable when viewing with an interactive renderer (`Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive == TRUE`). So this will make sure you never need to hit the next page button when viewing on the Report Server but it won't have any effect when exporting to a render format like PDF.

Answer (score 0):

It's a suggestion. You can change page size from letter to legal, and change from portrait to landscape.

Comment: Making the page margins smaller will help as well.